# Flutter Dart - Receiving non static member vars in StreamSubscription

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to save the result of the following StreamSubscription passing a non-static member variable _uid. which is not allowed. What workarounds are possible to make this work?

```
StreamSubscription < LocationResult > subscription = Geolocation.locationUpdates(

    accuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
    displacementFilter: 10.0, // in meters
    inBackground: true, // by default, location updates will pause when app is inactive (in background). Set to `true` to continue updates in background.
  )
  .listen((result) {
    if (result.isSuccessful) {

      saveResult(result, _uid);
    } else {

    }
  });
```

_uid is set during Widget build:

```
String _uid = UserModel.of(context).firebaseUser.uid;
```

I can't access _uid in saveResult() either since it's a static method.

Comment: how about making `String _uid` a static variable?

Comment: receive error Can't have static modifier here:

Comment: you have to define the static variable at the class level and then assign it in build method using context.

Comment: As simple as that, thanks a lot, still learining ;-)

Comment: My pleasure, happy Fluttering :)